# Database not appearing in MYSQL console

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I've created a database on phpmyadmin -

However, when I go to the MySql console, it doesn't appear.

Can someone shed some light on why this is?

I see that it doesn't show alot of the databases in phpmyadmin, and only test and informaion_schema.

Apparently I need 10 reputation before i can post images, so I couldn't show you the screen shots I had. I'm not sure what other information to give.

Thanks.

Comment: Both on the same db server?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by that. I'm only doing this in college so i'm not advanced or anything. I'm using the localhost server if that is what you are referring too?

Comment: *I'm using the localhost server if that is what you are referring too?* - yeah, that's fine; I've done something similar in the past with running 2 MySQL instances on the same machine (both localhost but on different ports) and temporarily confused myself in a similar manner... reading the answers though it sounds simply like you're using different MYSQL users with different permissions is all.

Answer (score 1):

It'll can be for the following reasons:

- Your user on phpmyadmin and console is different
- You have two version of mysql in your server and phpmyadmin connect to one of your database and console connected to another one